# Replace part of a string (column name) in Python or Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to replace a part of a string in Python or Pandas?

```
"xxsffsfdewetczxCATINTHEHATxxxxxxxxDrSeussfggfhgfh"
```

anything like the excel function (*CATINTHEHAT*DrSeuss) to replace the whole string and just keep those two sentences, 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

```
str.replace(old, new[, max])
```